# Regex in R: matching the string before a sequence of characters

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract a part of the string that comes before a certain word. E.g. I want to get everything before ", useless".

```
a <- "Experiment A, useless (03/25)"
b <- grep('^[^useless]+', a, perl=T)
regmatches(a,b)
```

This should return "Experiment A".

However, this doesn't work. R gives "Error in substring(x[ind], so, eo) : invalid substring arguments".

Comment: You want `regexpr` instead of `grep` here, if you want to pass the results to `regmatches`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `,` followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by 'useless' and other characters that follow (`.*`) and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub(",\\s*useless\\b.*", "", a)
#[1] "Experiment A"
```

Answer (score 3):

Lookahead is made for this:

```
b <- regexpr(".*(?=, useless)", a, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(a, b)
## [1] "Experiment A"
```

`.*` matches any sequence of characters, but the lookahead `(?=, useless)` says that it only matches text that is followed by the string ", useless".

Answer (score 1):

`sub("(\\w*), useless.*","\\1",a)`

Answer (score 0):

```
sub('(.*),.*','\\1', a, perl=T)
[1] "Experiment A"
```