# How to fetch 7 characters before and after a matched pattern in R

Tags: r, regex

Data :

```
"Danger Sign 14x10 Aluminum - No Smoking Beyond This Point"
```

Output Desired : First find the pattern "x" . Second, extract characters 7 indices before "x" and 7 indices after "x".

If anyone has any clue , please reply.

Comment: lol no , work assignment.

Comment: What did you try ? add the code to the post

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting and removing the first character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723549/getting-and-removing-the-first-character-of-a-string). If you look at the answer to this question, you will see that you just need to take a substring from the 0th element to the 6th element and the 8th element to the 14th element. Although, if you need a more general solution (using regex), then you will need something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012861/regex-in-r-matching-the-string-before-a-sequence-of-characters).

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `grep` and `substr`

```
ind <- grep("x", Data)
substr(Data, ind-7, ind+7)
```